# Why below regex removing one charter from string in group 1?

Tags: c#, regex

```
Regex rg = new Regex(@"[\d](.*)$", RegexOptions.Multiline);

rg.Match("6920 BIRDWOOD AVENUE, MIDDLE RIVER, MD 21220").Dump();
```

[image: I want 6920 BIRDWOOD AVENUE, MIDDLE RIVER, MD 21220]

Why in group 1 I got this 920 BIRDWOOD AVENUE, MIDDLE RIVER, MD 21220?

Is there any way to get 6920 BIRDWOOD AVENUE, MIDDLE RIVER, MD 21220 in group 1?

Thanks

Comment: You could move the digit into the group. `(\d.*)$`.

Comment: Read your regex pattern carefully. Your regex pattern says "_a numeric digit followed by a group (of all the remaining stuff until the end of the line/string)_" So, the regex is actually NOT removing a character from the group. The first numeric digit in the string is simply not part of the group. (In other words: you can't throw a passenger from a train if said passenger is not on the train to begin with...)